# How do I set an alternate stylesheet in XHTML similar to HTML?

Tags: css, xhtml

I am trying to add an alternate stylesheet to my XHTML page, but it doesn't work. I have done it with HTML, which works perfectly, but XHTML just doesn't do what I want.

The code looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title>some title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" title="normal"/>
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/blue.css" title="blue"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="styles">
            <a id="normal" href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('normal');"><img src="tomain.png" width="20" alt="change style"/></a>
            <a id="blue" href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('blue');"><img src="toblue.png" width="20" alt="change style"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <--!other stuff-->
</body>
```

Of course in the CSS file I added .header next to the header tag, etc. Everything else works fine for the HTML and XHTML with the same CSS files, I just can't change styles so I think the problem is with the XHTML, and not the CSS.

Comment: Alternate stylesheets definitely work in XHTML. What is the implementation of "setActiveStyleSheet()"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.